# creating ACTION_SEND intent fails with "Failure when grantUriPermission"

Tags: android, android-intent

i'm building a **send action intent** in my android app.
My Test Phone: Huawei
minsdk: 15
targetSdkVersion 28

i want that it launch the chooser intent, **(wanted Result)**

[image: Wanted Result!]

but it launch the default Huawei intent. **(Unwanted Result)**

[image: Current unwanted result]

here is my code:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "sdfd");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "qsxc");

Intent newIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "send to");
newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
startActivity(newIntent);
```

i'm trying many things, even i added this to my activity in manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity" >
    <!-- This activity handles "SEND" actions with text data -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Here is the error i'm getting:

```
W/Intent: Failure when grantUriPermission
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.net.Uri.writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel, int)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.grantUriPermission(ActivityManagerNative.java:4823)
        at android.content.Intent.migrateExtraStreamToClipData(Intent.java:9177)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1529)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4391)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4335)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4697)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4665)
        at com.chlegou.bitbot.activity.MainActivity.onNavigationItemSelected(MainActivity.java:120)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView$1.onMenuItemSelected(BottomNavigationView.java:204)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:840)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:158)
        at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:991)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView$1.onClick(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:115)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5646)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22459)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6523)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
```

Comment: have you set up file provider?

Comment: i didn't, i don't know how. i was reading about it, but didn't know how to set it up

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider check this, it helps you to set up one.

Comment: could you help me out with an example? i havn't experience with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i was able to reach desired result.
you could find it here, with the hint also. :)

link: https://github.com/zawadz88/material-activity-chooser/issues/6

Answer (score 1):

Create an xml file (for example file_provider_paths.xml) in xml resources folder:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="shared" path="shared/"/>
</paths>
```

In your ApplicationManifest.xml, add this provider inside application node:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="<your provider authority>"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
      android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

To share a file -

```
Uri sharedFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, <your provider auhtority>, sharedFile);
```

Using chooser intent:

```
ShareCompat.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this).addStream(sharedFileUri);
```

And start it:

```
Intent chooserIntent = intentBuilder.createChooserIntent();
startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Grant permission for intent
Before sharing your file, you’ll have to manually grant the permission (read and/or write), for all applications targeted with your intent. Indeed, you can’t know which one the user will choose to share the file with.

```
final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
final List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
for (ResolveInfo resolvedIntentInfo : activities) {
  final String packageName = resolvedIntentInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
  context.grantUriPermission(packageName, uri, permissions);
}
```

Comment: the thing is, i'm not trying to share a file, i'm sharing a simple string (text/plain) as my code is written. that's what is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Define provider in your `manifest.xml` inside `<application>` tag.

```
<provider
     android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"  
     android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"   <!--replace with your packagename.fileprovider-->
     android:exported="false"
     android:grantUriPermissions="true">
     ...
</provider>
```

Create a folder in res named `xml` inside it create `filepaths.xml` and paste following code inside it.

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." />
    <files-path name="files_path"  path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: how do i create the "fileprovider" ? this one     android:authorities="com.mydomain.fileprovider"

Comment: replace `com.mydomain` with your package name